# Architectural advice for AWS firehose or similar when collecting a lot of events in real-time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, architecture, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I would like to ask you about getting some advice about handling many application events on AWS. My application sends a lot of different events about everything what a user did in real-time. For collecting those events, I’m using AWS firehose (kinesis) - I have few data streams where I push some different events. Some events, before storing on S3/Redshift contains data which I want to extract and store to other databases (DynamoDB) or to other S3 files — for that case I’m using lambda which is assigned to a specific stream.

My problem is that business adds more and more new events which they need to collect or do something with data and for every new event or „group” events I need create separate data stream + s3/rs/es + lambda for extracting data. Also, events on S3 are stored in one format and there is not possible to group that events e.g. by userId from an application or even name of the event in the stream filename. Ideal s3 with that events would look like events/{user_id}/{date}/{event-name}{timestamp}.json.

Maybe I’m wrong using firehose or I have wrong thinking about firehose in my case, maybe there are other, better services on AWS for my case which can give me more control. Maybe simple SQS + lambdas as a listener on S3 is better solution in this case?

Thanks for any advice.

### **EDIT 12th Nov 2020**

This was supposed to be a comment for [@Lina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3024873/lina), but it was too long to put a comment, so I updated my question with the solution which I pick.

> I resolved my issue as I "felt", so it may not be a good way to repeat, but: I've written a nodejs routing application which I connected on firehose and I wrote a few microservices where data is sent from firehose by my routing app. So now, I have a firehose tube and I'm taking 10 different event types. When some event came, my routing application decides what microservice should be run with what data based on the event type (the raw firehose event is still stored on s3 automatically). This gives me needed flexibility as I can extract specific data from the event, do with that data what I need, by running every other microservices from the whole system and still have a raw event in the s3 in case of needed revert history of events.
>
> Some of the events are not passing to any service, it is just stored as a raw s3 file e.g. application logs - I can do many things with that files on S3 PUT/CREATE event.

I hope that it will help someone with a similar problem.

Comment: Did you get a proper suggestion/answer for your question? I have the same issue.

Comment: Hi @Lina - Thanks for reading my long question ;). I didn't get any answer or solution how to achieve it, but I edit my question and I added info how I resolved my problem. I hope that it will help you somehow.